# How to get user id from jwt token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, azure-active-directory, httpcontext

Net core application. Through swagger I am authenticating against my web api app. I am sending JWT token in each request from swagger. This jwt token contains Azure user objectid. I want to retrieve it. I tried as below.

```
userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.First(i => i.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

this is not giving me correct object identifier. I can see object identifier in my token as showed below.

[image: jwt token]

In below image there is object identifier but I am not able to retrieve it. Can someone help me on this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Umm, change your claim type filter to get the other claim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the name of claim you look for, you can just use it instead of the ones defined in `ClaimTypes` class.

```
userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.First(i => i.Type == "CLAIM_NAME").Value;
```

The `ClaimTypes` class is not an enum, it just contains some predefined const string values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So in my case I should pass full url? http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier

Comment: I looked at all the claims in the token and name isn't any one of them.